# Counting and adding distinct values that occur in certain dates using PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Using some SQL in the tables of some database, I get a result like this:

```
id  name    date            status
1   John    2018-05-03      PRESENT
2   Mary    2018-05-03      NOT PRESENT
3   Jane    2018-05-03      NOT PRESENT
2   Mary    2018-05-04      PRESENT
1   John    2018-05-04      PRESENT
1   John    2018-05-05      PRESENT
2   Mary    2018-05-05      NOT PRESENT
3   Jane    2018-05-04      PRESENT
3   Jane    2018-05-05      NOT PRESENT
1   John    2018-05-06      PRESENT
```

I wanna use further SQL to get in a result like this one:

```
id  name    date      present   not present
1   John    2018-05       4           0
2   Mary    2018-05       1           2
3   Jane    2018-05       2           1
```

In other words, I wanna extract how many classes a student attended in a given month, based on the status he/she received everyday. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `conditional aggregation` :

```
select id, name, to_char(date,'YYYY-MM') as "Date", 
       sum(case when status = 'PRESENT' then 1 else 0 end ) as present,
       sum(case when status = 'NOT PRESENT' then 1 else 0 end ) as not_present
  from tab
 group by id, name, "Date"
 order by id
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://rextester.com/GGLRV58973)</kbd>

- keeping `else 0` is important to get 0 for `null` returning cases
- column alias in the select list might be used in the `group by` list
  for Postgres
- due to the desired output, truncating date value to month by
  `to_char(date,'YYYY-MM')` is needed

Comment: Your solution worked just fine. I'm studying Postgresql right now, I'm much more a spreadsheet guy... and I just cannot guess what part of this code is "selecting by month". In my way of view things, you just truncated the date and them, magically, SQL understood by its own that it needs to aggregate every single date  in that month and sum the values. What am I not getting yet?

Comment: Hi @AndréCarvalho. `MM` represents the pattern `for month number from 01 to 12`, and that's used within `to_char` function function as the 2nd argument to convert a date value to a string, if year part included, then you meet `'YYYY-MM'` or `'YYYY.MM'` or `'YYYYMM'` depending on your displaying style.

Answer (score 0):

```
select id, name, to_char(date,'YYYY-MM') as date, 
       sum((case when status = 'PRESENT' then 1 end )) present,
       sum((case when status = 'NOT PRESENT' then 1 end )) not_present
  from your_result_table
 group by id, name, to_char(date,'YYYY-MM')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional aggregation (using `filter`) and `date_trunc()`:

```
select id, name, date_trunc('month', date),
       count(*) filter (where status = 'PRESENT') as num_present,
       count(*) filter (where status = 'NOT PRESENT') as num_notpresent
from t
group by id, name, date_trunc('month', date)
order by id, name, date_trunc('month', date)
```